# Get Rotativa PDF working on shared hosting

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, rotativa

I recently used the Rotativa nuget package for exporting an MVC view to PDF.

This worked locally as well as on a dedicated Windows server but does not work on shared hosting.

I get the generic Rotativa errors. I do not have access to change permissions to the executable and the hosting provider will not change permissions either.

What other solutions can I try to get this working on shared hosting?

Answer (score 3):

I came across a solution for this that worked for me.

The version that is currently in NuGet is an older version.

You need to go to http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html and download the latest stable release. For me it was the 64bit version as the shared hosting server is Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit.

This will download an EXE. Extract the EXE using 7Zip or WinRar or the likes.

Open the unzipped folder, look for the folder called bin. Copy the following :

- wkhtmltoimage.exe
- wkhtmltopdf.exe
- wkhtmltox.dll

FTP these files to your live sites wwwroot -> Rotativa folder. You will need to overwrite the existing files in that folder.

Now your PDF export action will work correctly for shared hosting.

Hope this saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks a lot , i have resolved my issue by following these steps. and now Rotativa working on shared hosting for me .

Answer (score 0):

It works for now but since Rotativa is using the wkhtmltopdf exe which is an executable outside of your code, you might experience again issues if you try to switch to another environment.

If portability is an issue i would roll with a 100% managed c# code library such as ITextSharp or HtmlRenderer for PDF in combination with RazorViewEngine for converting views to html code.